# Combine confidence intervals for daily predictions from Poisson/Neg. Binomial GLMs

Tags: r, confidence-interval, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-regression, aggregation

I have a number of Poisson GLMs relating a daily count to daily weather predictors. They've been assembled in R from time series of counts and observed weather, and they're represented by GLM objects in R like:

`glm(count ~ offset(log(population)) + dow + temp.max,
    family = poisson, data = myData)`

I can send new data, such as new observations or climate model output, to `predict.glm()` to get predicted daily count estimates. I understand that if I supply `se.fit = TRUE` to `predict.glm()`, I can get standard errors for each day's estimate—from which I can derive confidence intervals (for example, `+/- 1.96*SE`for a 95% CI).

Comparing the estimates for each model is a bit difficult in this form, though, especially as I'll be generating predictions for a number of time periods (2000–2009, 2080–2089, etc.). So what II'd like to do is aggregate these daily estimates into a mean daily count with an associated combined confidence interval. How would I go about this?

For bonus points, I'm looking at also running Negative Binomial GLMs using the MASS package's `glm.nb()` to fix overdispersion in my Poisson GLMs. Is the process of obtaining standard errors in R similar for NB GLMs, and could I still calculate aggregate estimates and CIs?

**EDIT:** to clarify, I'm not looking to combine the interval around one day's prediction in the Poisson model with the same day's in the NB model. I want to give a model a series of dates, make predictions with associated intervals for each day, and then *add up or average* those daily counts and come up with an interval for the *entire period of dates*.

Comment: For the confidence interval of the mixture distribution, you could 1) compute the mean and variance of both models (Poisson and NegBin), 2) get the corresponding mean and variance for the simple average of the two [this is a linear mixture distribution, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution for the first two moments], and 3) use this to construct a CI for the mean prediction.

Comment: @Fabian, are you recommending that I use a mixture distribution? I'm more interested in exactly how the mean predicton CI is derived from the daily prediction CIs/std errors in whichever distribution I use.